# Calculate and display time between two NSDates

Tags: ios, nsdate, nsdateformatter, nscalendar, nsdatecomponents

The initial objective is to calculate the difference between two NSDates using NSDateComponents. Furthermore, once the days, hours, minutes, and seconds have been obtained and verified as correct. Display a real-time ticker (counter) with the difference (to the nearest minute, hour, or day) within a UITableViewCell.
Current progress can be found below.
Any suggestions, or direction in accomplishing this will be greatly appreciated!

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  static NSString *CellIdentifier =@"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
cell.textLabel.text = [(AGSGraphic *)[_radios objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] attributeForKey:@"parent_id"];

NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[df setDateFormat:@"YYYY-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"];

NSNumber *timestamp = [[_radios objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"date_time_edt"];
NSDate *today = [NSDate date];

NSDate *crewDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:[timestamp doubleValue]/1000];
NSString *temp = [df stringFromDate:today];
NSString *crewtemp = [df stringFromDate:crewDate];
crewDate = [df dateFromString:crewtemp];
today = [df dateFromString:temp];
NSLog(@"%@", crewDate);
NSLog(@"%@", today);
NSTimeInterval interval = [crewDate timeIntervalSinceDate:today];
interval = -interval;

NSInteger minutes = interval/60;
NSInteger hours = minutes/60;
NSInteger days = hours/24;
//    NSInteger weeks = days/7;
//    NSInteger months = weeks/4;
//    NSInteger years = months/12;


//    NSTimeInterval years = interval/31536000;
//    NSTimeInterval months = years/12;
//    NSTimeInterval weeks = years/52;
//    NSTimeInterval days = years/365;
//    NSTimeInterval hours = days/24;
//    NSTimeInterval minutes = hours/60;

//    NSLog(@"%f", interval);

if(minutes < 60)
{
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld minuntes ago", (long)minutes];
}
else if(hours < 24)
{
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld hours ago", (long)hours];
}
else
{
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld days ago", (long)days];
}

return cell;
}
```

Comment: NSDateIntervalFormatter

Comment: Can you give an example or two of what you want the final string to look like?

Comment: YYYY-MM-dd hh:mm:ss, from here I would pass the components into a method that would print to the screen the difference (rounded to the nearest minute, hour, or day)

Comment: Rounded to the nearest hour, minute, or day, but you still want to use a format string that includes seconds (the `ss`)?

Answer (score 0):

here's how you do it with Minutes:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSHLessonCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:NSHLessonCellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSDate *fromDate;
    NSDate *toDate;

    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];

    [calendar rangeOfUnit:NSCalendarUnitMinute startDate:&fromDate interval:NULL forDate:[self.ninjas[indexPath.row] started]];    
    [calendar rangeOfUnit:NSCalendarUnitMinute startDate:&toDate interval:NULL forDate:[self.ninjas[indexPath.row] finished]];
    NSDateComponents *difference = [calendar components:NSCalendarUnitMinute fromDate:fromDate toDate:toDate options:0];

    [cell setTotalDuration:[difference minute]];
}
```

Also, I would only assume that using the method for minutes that I use, you can also use other methods for calculating difference for different units of date measurements by swapping out NSCalendarUnitMinute with options provided in NSCalendar.h, see below:

```
typedef NS_OPTIONS(NSUInteger, NSCalendarUnit) {
        NSCalendarUnitEra                = kCFCalendarUnitEra,
        NSCalendarUnitYear               = kCFCalendarUnitYear,
        NSCalendarUnitMonth              = kCFCalendarUnitMonth,
        NSCalendarUnitDay                = kCFCalendarUnitDay,
        NSCalendarUnitHour               = kCFCalendarUnitHour,
        NSCalendarUnitMinute             = kCFCalendarUnitMinute,
        NSCalendarUnitSecond             = kCFCalendarUnitSecond,
        NSCalendarUnitWeekday            = kCFCalendarUnitWeekday,
        NSCalendarUnitWeekdayOrdinal     = kCFCalendarUnitWeekdayOrdinal,
        NSCalendarUnitQuarter            NS_ENUM_AVAILABLE(10_6, 4_0) = kCFCalendarUnitQuarter,
        NSCalendarUnitWeekOfMonth        NS_ENUM_AVAILABLE(10_7, 5_0) = kCFCalendarUnitWeekOfMonth,
        NSCalendarUnitWeekOfYear         NS_ENUM_AVAILABLE(10_7, 5_0) = kCFCalendarUnitWeekOfYear,
        NSCalendarUnitYearForWeekOfYear  NS_ENUM_AVAILABLE(10_7, 5_0) = kCFCalendarUnitYearForWeekOfYear,
        NSCalendarUnitNanosecond         NS_ENUM_AVAILABLE(10_7, 5_0) = (1 << 15),
        NSCalendarUnitCalendar           NS_ENUM_AVAILABLE(10_7, 4_0) = (1 << 20),
        NSCalendarUnitTimeZone           NS_ENUM_AVAILABLE(10_7, 4_0) = (1 << 21),
```

Comment: If you wouldn't mind elaborating on the the origin of "started/finished" It would be appreciated!

Comment: Okay, just realized those are BOOL(s)

Comment: Yes, I have actually managed to accomplish the objective. I will update the original code! Thank you for your help and courtesy to follow up. @Larcerax